# Date archive permalink modification

Tags: permalinks, rewrite-rules

I did little tweak for date archive permalink.

```
function my_rewrite_rules($wp_rewrite){
    $rules = array();
    $rules['news/([0-9]{4})/?$'] = 'index.php?year=$matches[1]';
    $wp_rewrite->rules = $rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}

add_action('generate_rewrite_rules', 'my_rewrite_rules');
```

Then hit the url below.

```
http://blahblah.blahblah/wp/news/2017/
```

This successfully shows posts belong to 2017.

Now I want to generate the links for date archive, but this doesn't generate the code I want.

```
get_year_link($year);
```

Still generate the default permalink like this:

```
http://blahblah.blahblah/wp/date/2017/
```

So how do I tell wordpress what permastructure to use?
Otherwise I may have to hard code...

Comment: Did you update your permalinks? **Settings > Permalinks > Hit Save**

Comment: @JunaidAhmed Yes, I did update the permalink setting. But still gives me `date/{$yyyy}` link.

Comment: I may found a hook to alter the yearlink. Correct me if I am wrong.
`add_filter('year_link', function($yearlink, $year){ return home_url(user_trailingslashit('news/'.$year)); }, 10, 2);`

Answer (score 2):

You can change the date links by directly modifying the `date_structure`:

```
function wpd_change_date_structure(){
    global $wp_rewrite;
    $wp_rewrite->date_structure = 'news/%year%/%monthnum%/%day%';
}
add_action( 'init', 'wpd_change_date_structure' );
```

Don't forget to flush rewrite rules after the change.

WordPress will use this to generate the rewrite rules for incoming requests as well as URL output when using API functions like `get_year_link`, so there's no need for a filter.

Answer (score 1):

Yes norixxx, your comment above is the right answer:

```
add_filter('year_link', 'change_year_link', 10, 2);
function change_year_link($yearlink, $year){
  return home_url(user_trailingslashit('news/'.$year));
}
```

And thank you for sharing!

Below, users can find an 'expanded' version:

```
// generate /year, /year/month, /year/month/post-slug rules
add_action('generate_rewrite_rules', 'rewrite_rules');
function rewrite_rules($wp_rewrite){
  $rules = array();
  $rules['news/([0-9]{4})/?$'] = 'index.php?year=$matches[1]';
  $rules['news/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/?$'] = 'index.php?year=$matches[1]&monthnum=$matches[2]';
  $rules['news/([0-9]{4})/([0-9]{2})/([^/]+)/?$'] = 'index.php?year=$matches[1]&monthnum=$matches[2]&name=$matches[3]';
  $wp_rewrite->rules = $rules + $wp_rewrite->rules;
}


add_filter('year_link', 'change_year_link', 10, 2);
function change_year_link($yearlink, $year){
  return home_url(user_trailingslashit('news/'.$year));
}

add_filter('month_link', 'change_month_link', 10, 2);
function change_month_link($yearlink, $year, $month){
  return home_url(user_trailingslashit('news/'.$year.'/'.$month));
}

// this last is for generating /year/month/post-slug links
// I think it can be optional. Keep in mind that by applying this filter,
// You won't be able to manually modify the slug in admin edit post view
add_filter('post_link', 'set_post_links' , 10, 2);
function set_post_links($permalink, $post){
  if(is_wp_error($post) || empty($post->post_name)) return $permalink;

  if('post' == $post->post_type){
    $year = get_the_date('Y', $post->ID);
    $month = get_the_date('m', $post->ID);
    return home_url(user_trailingslashit("$year/$month/$post->post_name"));
  }

  return $permalink;
} 


// If you use the post_link filter, 
// probably you'll want to auto-update post slugs upon post title modifications. 
// Here's how:
add_filter('wp_insert_post_data', 'update_post_data' , 10, 2);
function update_post_data($data, $postarr){
  // protect non-post posts
  if($data['post_type'] !== 'post') return $data;

  $data['post_name'] = wp_unique_post_slug(sanitize_title($data['post_title']), $postarr['ID'], $data['post_status'], $data['post_type'], $data['post_parent']);
  return $data;
}
```