# Date-based archive URLs to match my /2023/Jun/13 permalink structure?

Tags: permalinks, archives

So, I have a custom function that adds a `%monthname%` variable to use in permalink settings instead of the native `%monthnum%`, so that I can have the three-letter month abbreviation in post URLs because I find it more human-readable, and that works fine.

What I haven't yet been able to figure out is how I can—or even whether I can—
have the date-based archives also use the same structure with the three-letter month abbreviation.

Caveat: if anything requires rewrites (although, to be clear, I don't want /2023/Jun/13/ to redirect to /2023/06/13/, I want the actual URL to be /2023/Jun/13/) I'm using nginx and my understanding is that therefore I can't use `add_rewrite_rule()` and would need to know/learn how to do them in nginx itself.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Date archive permalink modification](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/272128/date-archive-permalink-modification)

Comment: Hrm. I can't tell. It's not clear to me if I don't understand how to incorporate the `%monthname%` there (simply dropping it in doesn't work), or if because that seems to involve rewrites, it needs more work in my case because nginx.

Comment: To confirm: did you make the changes necessary for your implementation, and flush your rewrite rules?

Comment: I made what changes I thought I understood based upon that other question. I'm not a programmer; sometimes I can understand enough of what some bit of code is doing to make it work for me, sometimes not. I am not sure what you mean about flushing rewrite rules. I did re-save the permalinks settings page. (But if there's deeper rewrite stuff, as I suggest above that gets into the weeds for me as WordPress under nginx can't use WP's built-in rewrite stuff, as I understand it.) Thanks.